# What's the plan for getting realtime live updates to GraphQL queries?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Facebook's own product uses GraphQL and is also a great example of a realtime experience. E.g. when someone likes something, everyone can see the like appear in their feed.

But all of the documentation for GraphQL uses a stateless server where every query is like making an HTTP GET or HTTP POST at a single point in time.

So it's not clear how the average developer will be able to build something as realtime as Facebook itself.

E.g. what kind of state will the server track when we have realtime GraphQL? Will the client send over a bundle of GraphQL queries to watch? Or will the server track a higher-level aspect of the client's state to infer which GraphQL queries the client cares about watching?

Comment: I imagine you could always use Socket.IO to notify you to update. I wouldn't be surprised if they don't do something similar. But Facebook is actually not that real time. I've never seen comments, which are a part done in ReactJS, be updated in real time. You could also poll the server an interval or play with Server Side Events (but this is unsupported in older browsers)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question and all answers are speculative: "how will it work once it's built?"